# Send many parallel fetch request (more than max browser support)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, browser, es6-promise, fetch-api

I want to know: if I want to send multiple fetch request, that exceeds max browser parallel request support, can I send all request in parallel
and browser automatically will handle them? or I should first shrink them to sufficient size bunches and chain them.

`Promise.all([allpromisses])`

or any other solutions like:

```js
    function fetchAll(urls) {
        const requestPromises = urls.map(url => {
          return fetch(url).then(response => response.json());
        });
    
        requestPromises.reduce((chain, requestPromise) => {
          return chain.then(() => requestPromise)
            .then(data => data);
        }, Promise.resolve());
      }
```

**or**

```
getBunch([promises1]).then(getBunch([promises2]). ...
```

Comment: Hi Hamed, how did you solve that please? I have the same issue, I am sending several fetches at the same time and I have to wait more than a minute for the response to arrive, which is too long for a web app. If I limit the number of fetches to less than 6 or 7 then it arrives in a instant

Comment: Hi.  If you want to use result on sequence you send them, you can use async method and inside for loop use await inside it and then use the result by sequence. or you can chain the promises of the fetch by reduce method.

Comment: Thanks. If I understand right, I am doing something along the lines of the first case you describe. I have posted a question on SO about this, if you dont mind you could have a look and see exactly what I have done. I just have not found a way to handle many requests (more than what is allowed b the browser). Response takes ages to return

Comment: I read your question and I think your problem is not related to browser parallel request limit.

Comment: ok, many thanks. Appreciate your time you spent looking into this

Comment: So the answer to this depends if you are using http/1.1 or http/2, since 2 will multiplex on one connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to continue until all of the fetches return, it's worth just using `Promise.all()` and letting the browser handle queuing the requests. One nice thing is that `Promise.all()` will "fail fast". Meaning that unless you're handing errors individually, one failed promise will reject the `Promise.all()`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#Promise.all_fail-fast_behaviour

Comment: Thank you @Ed Lucas, I edited my question. My question was more about the queuing by the browser or handling it in the code and as you said It should not be matter. is it right?

Comment: Yes. Since the browser is the limitation, I'd let it queue the requests the best that it's able.